# Can System Admin bypass required (lookup) fields?

Tags: apex, update, before-trigger

A user was trying to create a child record but they were getting an error because of other associated record has a required (lookup) field blank. But i was able to create it when i tried as system admin and not when logged in as same user as mentioned above.

Is there a way to bypass required fields through Apex Triggers?

**Below screenshots are related to my comment made on [12/21/2018 10:05 AM]**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems its already bypassing it. Can you elaborate more on the issue? A required field can be marked by different ways, viz., validation rule, page layout, api level, so what is the current state as how is the field marked as required?

Comment: Some orgs choose to not make validation rules fire for system administrators, if a validation rule is the source of the error. System Administrators can't bypass database-level required fields.

Comment: @JayantDas Field is made required on Page Layout. Object belongs to a Managed Package, Debug logs is showing me below exception when tried as a different user but goes through as System Admin 

`Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a2vt0000000PPMRAA4; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MUSW.Permit2SequenceNumber: execution of BeforeUpdate

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Class.MUSW.Sequ`

Comment: So if the field was required on the page layout, how did you end up bypassing that? Fields marked on page layout are applicable for all users, if you created record using say Apex, then there are always ways to bypass those fields marked as required on page layout. Still not clear what is your issue here.

Comment: @JayantDas Sorry, I had to try out few scenarios before answering that question. It appears that "Modify All" is overriding the system. I gave the same user "Modify All" permission to the object and now even the user can update the record without the required field filled-in (update is happening through apex though). Please see the screenshots i posted in my question above. Thanks!